# What is the Fourier transform of a "geometric delta comb?"

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, mellin-transform

An ordinary delta comb can be defined as

$$Ш(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-n)$$

The (distributional) Fourier transform of this is equal to another delta comb with frequency inverse to the original. In the case of a unit-period delta comb, the Fourier transform is equal to itself.

Consider instead a delta comb which follows the pattern of a geometric series, with a weighting term:

$$\tilde{Ш}_r(x,a) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{nr}\delta(x-a^n)$$

Note we can also write that as

$$\tilde{Ш}_r(x,a) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{r}\delta(x-a^n)$$

This appears to be a tempered distribution for any $r>1$.

If it's simpler, I'd also be interested in an answer in which the lower bound on the summation is some arbitrary integer, such as 0 or a negative number...

$$\tilde{Ш}_r(x,a) = \sum_{n=i}^\infty x^{r}\delta(x-a^n)$$

**What is the Fourier transform of $
\widetilde{Ш}_r(x,a)$?** Does there exist a closed-form solution?

Comment: I don't think that's a tempered distribution.

Comment: The first one certainly is, as it's even sparser than an ordinary Dirac comb (which is a tempered distribution). The second one also appears to be, by my reckoning (note it is also equal to the first times $x^r$.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem now - it's the asymptote at 0 that screws things up. I think you're right. I should change the lower bound on the summation to 0.

Comment: I edited my post to only have the version with the weighting term. This looks like it's a tempered distribution for any $r>0$. The original distribution was the special case with $r=0$. I'd still like to see if I can get an answer for this first before changing the bounds.

Comment: Oops, I think it's rather $r > 1$...